Time display on top bar displays k:17 instead of 15:17
I just updated to Ubuntu 24.4 LTS from I believe Ubuntu 22 LTS, but now my gnome time display is broken. Instead of displaying the hour, it displays a "k". Does someone know what broke or what I did incorrectly? Thanks!
screenshot

Install Extension Manager then use it to install Panel Date Formatto correct the date settings in the panel.

That worked thanks!

In the event that someone else has the same issue, perhaps you would be kind enough to accept the answer by clicking the grey tick. Thanks.

Install extension manager then use it to install Panel Date Format to correct any misformed entry and change it at the same time to what you would like it to be.
Click on the cog wheel icon and you will be presented with the following to guide you as to the options available.

